# #SpringBoot: HandleInterceptor preHandle throw Exception in html format

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-boot

I am trying to put interceptor to handle my custom authentication logic. So my prehandler will throw an exception if person in not logged in . I have my ErrorHandler controller added in script[/error] which gives json formatted error.

But when prehandler throws an exception it's all in html format, can i redirect my request to /error controller or if possible give my response in json format.

Script

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    throw new Exception("HELLO");
}
```

}

**Current Output**

```
<title>Apache Tomcat/8.5.11 - Error report</title>
```

## HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: HELLO

[image: Error]

**Expected Output**

```
{"timestamp":1496584878547,"status":500,"error":"Found","message":"Hello"}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution by yourself already? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062311/how-to-use-exceptionhandler-in-spring-interceptor) we cannot directly use controller advice with handlers. Here is how i have achieved it.

- Create json string for error message
- Use HttpServletResponse to write this error message to downstream

Ex.

```
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws IOException {
        final String tenantId = request.getHeader(X_TENANT_ID);
        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(tenantId)) {
            return returnErrorResponse(response);
        } else {
            Assert.notNull(tenantId, tenantExceptionMessage);
            TenantIdContext.setTenantIdContext(tenantId);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Error message implementation

```
private boolean returnErrorResponse(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        final int httpErrorCode = HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST;
        response.setStatus(httpErrorCode);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        final String jsonMessage = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new TenantIdMissing(tenantExceptionMessage.get(), httpErrorCode));
        System.out.println(jsonMessage);
        response.getWriter().write(jsonMessage);
        return false;
    }
```

Object mapper as instance variable for lazy devs to create json string.

```java
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Another good [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354894/springboot-handleinterceptor-prehandle-throw-exception-in-html-format/74385451#74385451)